# ServiceStack.Redis Unable to connect to Digitalocean managed redis instance

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, digital-ocean, servicestack.redis

Recently I started converting a job processor from Node.js to .net core and have chosen to use ServiceStack.Redis to manage the connection to Redis.

Annoyingly I can't get it to connect to the managed Redis without it throwing an exception. Any clues as to what this error even means?

```
var redisManager = new BasicRedisClientManager(0,Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REDIS"));
var redis = redisManager.GetClient();
```

```
Unhandled exception. ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException: unknown command `ROLE`, with args beginning with: 
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.ReadComplexResponse() in C:\BuildAgent\work\b2a0bfe2b1c9a118\src\ServiceStack.Redis\RedisNativeClient_Utils.cs:line 1075
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendReceive[T](Byte[][] cmdWithBinaryArgs, Func`1 fn, Action`1 completePipelineFn, Boolean sendWithoutRead) in C:\BuildAgent\work\b2a0bfe2b1c9a1
18\src\ServiceStack.Redis\RedisNativeClient_Utils.cs:line 616
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendExpectComplexResponse(Byte[][] cmdWithBinaryArgs) in C:\BuildAgent\work\b2a0bfe2b1c9a118\src\ServiceStack.Redis\RedisNativeClient_Utils.cs:l
ine 744
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.Role() in C:\BuildAgent\work\b2a0bfe2b1c9a118\src\ServiceStack.Redis\RedisNativeClient.cs:line 846
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.GetServerRole() in C:\BuildAgent\work\b2a0bfe2b1c9a118\src\ServiceStack.Redis\RedisClient.cs:line 1065
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResolver.CreateRedisClient(RedisEndpoint config, Boolean master) in C:\BuildAgent\work\b2a0bfe2b1c9a118\src\ServiceStack.Redis\RedisResolver.cs:line 84
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResolver.CreateMasterClient(Int32 desiredIndex) in C:\BuildAgent\work\b2a0bfe2b1c9a118\src\ServiceStack.Redis\RedisResolver.cs:line 148
   at ServiceStack.Redis.BasicRedisClientManager.GetClient() in C:\BuildAgent\work\b2a0bfe2b1c9a118\src\ServiceStack.Redis\BasicRedisClientManager.cs:line 104
```

Comment: I think you can check for either: 

1. check via `redis-cli` whether you can execute `ROLE` on your Redis nodes. It's possible that `ROLE` is disabled or not available on your Redis server.

2. Since you are using managed Redis service, you might want to use `PooledRedisClientManager` ?

Comment: @Sharif You are right, ROLE wasn't available on the managed instance. I managed to disable it by setting ```RedisConfig.VerifyMasterConnections = false;```

Comment: Glad my comment helped

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else gets stuck with this, in particular if you are using Managed REDIS from DigitalOcean.

Essentially the ROLE command (and possibly others) are not available, so in this library you have to set the following flag.

```csharp
RedisConfig.VerifyMasterConnections = false;
```